# [Ionic][Onesignal] How to refresh page when notification clicked

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I want my app automatically refresh to retrieve latest data from API whenever user press the notification sent by onesignal pushnotification server. Below is my sample code, I having trouble to call controller function to dorefresh() from App.js. Or is there any other workaround can let me retrieve latest data?

**App.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {    
// Enable to debug issues.
// window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    //alert("Notification received:\n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    //console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    $rootScope.openedFromNotification = true;
    alert($rootScope.openedFromNotification);
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $window.location.reload(true);
};


// Update with your OneSignal AppId and googleProjectNumber before running.
window.plugins.OneSignal.init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                               {googleProjectNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
                                notificationOpenedCallback);                                
  });
})
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',['ionic'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
$http.get("localhost/test/getitem.php")
.success(function (response) 
{
    $scope.items = response;
}); 

$scope.doRefresh = function() {

    console.log("Refreshing!");
    $http.get("localhost/test/getitem.php")
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.items = formatData(response);
    })
    .finally(function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete')
    })

};
```

**Index.html**

```
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh" on-refresh="doRefresh()">               
    </ion-refresher>
    <div class="item">
            <h2 style="text-align:center; font-size:25px; font-weight:">{{item.name}}</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: poklin, if you're happy with the answer, could you please, accept it? Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can broadcast an event in the `notificationOpenedCallback`:

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    //alert("Notification received:\n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    //console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    $rootScope.openedFromNotification = true;
    alert($rootScope.openedFromNotification);
    // $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    // $window.location.reload(true);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('app:notification', {refresh: true});
};
```

As you can see I've created a custom event `app:notification` and used the `$rootScope` to broadcast it (`$broadcast`) to the children scopes.
I've attached an object with some info your receiver can use.

Now in your controller you can intercept the event using `$scope.$on` and call your refresh function:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',['ionic'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

    $scope.$on('app:notification', function(event, data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.refresh)
        {
            $scope.doRefresh();
        }
    });
});
```

NOTES:

You don't really need to clean the cache here `$ionicHistory.clearCache();`.